# Jquery autocomplete from json data

Tags: jquery

i have country related data stored as json. i want to show country name from that json array. i use jquery autocomplete. this is my code which i tried but not working. give me some hint that where is the mistake.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="plugins" name="plugins" />

var myData =[
    {"name": "Afghanistan"},
    {"name": "Åland Islands"},
    {"name": "Albania"},
    {"name": "Algeria"},
    {"name": "American Samoa"},
    {"name": "Bahamas"},
    {"name": "Bahrain"},
    {"name": "Bangladesh"},
    {"name": "Barbados"},
    {"name": "Belarus"},
    {"name": "Belgium"},
    {"name": "Belize"},
    {"name": "Benin"},
    {"name": "Cambodia"},
    {"name": "Cameroon"},
    {"name": "Canada"},
    {"name": "Cape Verde"},
    {"name": "Cayman Islands"},
    {"name": "Viet Nam"},
    {"name": "Virgin Islands, British"},
    {"name": "Virgin Islands, U.S."},
    {"name": "Wallis and Futuna"},
    {"name": "Western Sahara"},
    {"name": "Yemen"},
    {"name": "Zambia"},
    {"name": "Zimbabwe"}
]

$(function() {
  $("#plugins").autocomplete({
    source: function(req, resp) {
      var results = [];
      $.each(myData, function(k, v) {
        // Make a pass for names
        if (v.name.indexOf(req.term) != -1) {
          results.push(v);
          return;
        }
      });
      resp(results);
    }
  });
});
```

here is jsfiddle version https://jsfiddle.net/urtkxo46/2/

this is working version of jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/durga598/urtkxo46/5/

Comment: Do you need to use the function variant?  If the list of options is fixed (as countries is) then the easiest solution is to update your list so it's simply an array of strings, then use `source:myData` rather than the function.  the autocomplete UI will take care of the rest

Comment: can u please tell me which line i need to change to get the code working.

Comment: that said, I think the actual source of your error is that `results.push(v)` should be `results.push(v.name)`

Comment: @GPW thanks a lot your hint solve my problem https://jsfiddle.net/urtkxo46/3/

Comment: i use if (v.name.indexOf(req.term) != -1) it search any character but i want to search input char start with. how to do it with js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your result array you need to push `results.push(v.name);` to match case insensitive use toLowerCase() , so it will match all the values properly.
You need to use [source](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source) an array or string or a function returns object with `key: label` and value .

```js
/*var myData = [{
  label: "xxx",
  value: "9997515744"
}, {
  label: "abc",
  value: "9619054073"
}, {
  label: "asd",
  value: "9323135708"
}];*/

var myData =[
 {"name": "Afghanistan"},
 {"name": "Åland Islands"},
 {"name": "Albania"},
 {"name": "Algeria"},
 {"name": "American Samoa"},
 {"name": "Bahamas"},
 {"name": "Bahrain"},
 {"name": "Bangladesh"},
 {"name": "Barbados"},
 {"name": "Belarus"},
 {"name": "Belgium"},
 {"name": "Belize"},
 {"name": "Benin"},
 {"name": "Cambodia"},
 {"name": "Cameroon"},
 {"name": "Canada"},
 {"name": "Cape Verde"},
 {"name": "Cayman Islands"},
 {"name": "Viet Nam"},
 {"name": "Virgin Islands, British"},
 {"name": "Virgin Islands, U.S."},
 {"name": "Wallis and Futuna"},
 {"name": "Western Sahara"},
 {"name": "Yemen"},
 {"name": "Zambia"},
 {"name": "Zimbabwe"}
]

$(function() {
  $("#plugins").autocomplete({
    source: function(req, resp) {
      var results = [];
      $.each(myData, function(k, v) {
        if (v.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(req.term.toLowerCase())) {
          results.push(v.name);
          return;
        }
      });
      //console.log(results)
      resp(results);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="plugins" name="plugins" />
```

Comment: Code only answers can get downvoted... you should add an explanation

Comment: i use if (v.name.indexOf(req.term) != -1) it search any character but i want to search input char start with. how to do it with js?

Comment: @Thomas That's why I am converting to lowercase. Check the snippet.

Comment: @Thomas do you need input character at first position only?

Comment: suppose when i type b then country name start with C is coming which i do not want. i test this `if (v.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(req.term.toLowerCase()) != -1) {` but did not work. still when i search with B then country name start with C is coming which is wrong.

Comment: @Thomas you can use `startsWith()` or check index == 0 instead of -1. Updated answer

Comment: see https://jsfiddle.net/urtkxo46/4/ still startsWith and ==0 is not helping. when i enter B then so many country come which start with C or other char.

Comment: @Thomas see the code snippet here or updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/durga598/urtkxo46/5/)

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs: [http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/]

The result of the response function needs to be an array of strings, or an array of objects with `label` and `value` properties.  You're returning an array of objects with a `"name"` property.

`results.push(v)` should be `results.push(v.name)` and then it'll be an array of strings so should work.

Comment: i use if (v.name.indexOf(req.term) != -1) it search any character but i want to search input char start with. how to do it with js?

Comment: can't you just use `v.name.indexOf(req.term) === 0)` ?  that'll only be true if it matches at the start